# Wallet sync restarts from block 0 after closing and launch

Tags: wallets, synchronization, mac-osx

I downloaded the Ethereum-wallet for OSX and started the sync. It took like 10 hours to sync more than 1M blocks.

I closed the wallet and restarted today, but I was surprised to see that the sync is starting from block 0.

Is it normal that the sync restart from 0 after closing the wallet?  If not, any thoughts on why this happened?

Comment: Ethereum blockchain is more than 25GB

Comment: @Nikhil M. du -hs ./ethereum/chaindata currently gives me the output of '13G chaindata/'. You may have included the DAG and other files in your 25Gb total.

Comment: @BokkyPooBah on a `fast` sync the size is even smaller mine is `4.2G` and is fully synced.

Comment: @Nikhil M I suspect that this is because only the receipts from the transactions and the resulting state changes get download and not the transactions.

Comment: @BokkyPooBah yeah, thats what `fast` supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you terminate Ethereum Wallet before the `--fast` syncing completed.

From the code in [mist/modules/ethereumNodes.js lines 175-183](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/master/modules/ethereumNodes.js#L175-L183), Ethereum Wallet will try to `--fast` sync the blockchain.

Referring to the answer [Geth node starts to sync from the beginning after fast sync](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/ethereum-mining-after-fast-sync), you may have to:

- Clear out your existing chaindata
- Restart Ethereum Wallet, and let it complete the syncing process fully.